# Genesis child theme - Remove primary sidebar on homepage only

Tags: wordpress

I have been looking all over the place and am unable to find a solution. I am using Genesis Child theme "news" and for the homepage I don't need the primary sidebar, because I'll have an image slider there instead. I have found code such as this:

```
/** Force full width layout */
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', 'child_do_layout' );
function child_do_layout( $opt ) {
$opt = 'full-width-content'; // You can change this to any Genesis layout below
return $opt;
}
```

and added it to the functions page, because I want to essentially force a full width page for home.php, however it hasn't worked.

If anyone has had success with this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, I found the solution to anyone who is curious, to the home.php file add:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
```